# Can I use HSRP for router hardware redundancy?

Tags: cisco, routing, router, hsrp, fhrp

I need solution for router hardware redundancy. Two routers 2900 series with same configuration, toward same ISP. If one fail second to do failover. Can HSRP do this? Can outside interfaces be set toward same ISP with same public ip address on outside interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSRP can provide first hop redundancy on your LAN. There are options to change the active router for things like router or link failure.

Each outside interface needs its own IP address from the ISP. Each inside interface needs its own IP address plus one more for the virtual IP address.

Comment: Ok, so I need two different ip addresses from ISP, but I have only one. Can I do something to achive router redundancy? Two physical routers one logical. Or some kind of failover?

Comment: There are several ways to do that. It really depends on the equipment you have and its capabilities. Some models can't do this, but some vendors have solutions for this.

Comment: in VRRP it's not mandatory that the routers IP are in the same network as the virtual IP, but I don't know if this config is supported on Cisco routers.

Comment: The question is only for outside interfaces. They are problem because I have only one public IP address.

Comment: As i commented, it depends on what equipment and software you have. There are ways to do it, but it is going to be vendor-dependent. HSRP is Cisco-specific, but it won't work for your outside interfaces.

Comment: I have two routers 2900 series. Can you tell me my options. If I have options.

Comment: With that equipment, you need two addresses from your ISP. HSRP works well on them, but it is for your LAN. You need to work with your ISP, some will provide you with a second address, some may give you a backup link with its own IP address and not charge for it unless you use it, etc. What options you have from your ISP is completely dependent on what it offers.

Answer (score -2):

hsrp and glbp are the good soultions for router redundancy

Comment: That's true, from inside the LAN toward the multiple routers, but he OP wants his routers, themselves, to have redundancy toward the ISP, and that is completely different since it would be the ISP needing to run the FHRP.